# Atiyah Bott-Shapiro orientation Vs Anderson-Brown-Peterson Splitting

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Are  the  [Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro Orientation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K-orientation#UniversalAtiyahBottShapiroOrientation) and  the [Anderson-Brown-Peterson Splitting](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183527786) compatible  in  any  sense?

The  first guess is  that  the ABS-Orientation  is  related  to  the   projections  on the  $BO\langle 4(n(J))\rangle$, respectively $BO\langle 4(n(J))-2\rangle$ factors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to  Michael Hopkins, Mark Hovey, *[Spin cobordism determines real K-theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/HopkinsHoveyCobordismK.pdf),* Mathematische Zeitschrift 210.1 (1992): 181-196, 4th page of the pdf file, the   Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro Orientation is just one of the Anderson-Brown-Peterson Splitting map $\pi ^0$.  Now, according to the paper by  Anderson-Brown-Peterson, the discussion between Theorem 1.3 and Corollary 1.4, this map is just the projection to the "bottom summand" $BO\langle 0 \rangle $.